# Color window in hbrBackground

Tags: c++, windows

```
WNDCLASS wc;
...
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
```

I could not undestand what is `+1` for and what is `HBRUSH`?

Comment: I think your question has a typo. Passing `COLOR_WINDOW + 1` to `GetStockObject` makes no sense.

Comment: but that's what u'll find in msdn site for setting the background in windows

Comment: Um, [there is no `GetStockObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/bb384843.aspx).

Comment: i am just asking about color_window+1??

Comment: One answer is "Why ask why?" The rules are to add 1, so add 1. The reason is not important. But the reason is that it ensures that the result is never 0.

Comment: @Abhineet There is absolutely nothing that is up to the Stack Overflow standards about this question. For starters, the code sample is not even correctly formatted. Then, the title doesn't make any sense (it isn't even a complete thought), the question text is completely ungrammatical and nonsensical, it doesn't explain what the person has tried to find out by their own research, etc. I'm surprised it has only 1 downvote...

Comment: @RaymondChen "The reason is not important." -- I realise that being Raymond Chen gives you some leverage by default, but I find that statement disagreeable. If one doesn't understand the reason why an API is a certain way, then the reason could be (1) so ingenious, or (2) such a terrible mistake, that either way understanding the reason means you are improving your own skills by learning from others. Even though in this particular case, the reason is rather unimpactful, it could still sensitize a programmer to think twice before defining a zero value in a bunch of predefined IDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System Colors defined in `Winuser.h`

```
#define CTLCOLOR_MSGBOX 0

#define CTLCOLOR_EDIT 1

#define CTLCOLOR_LISTBOX 2

#define CTLCOLOR_BTN 3

#define CTLCOLOR_DLG 4

#define CTLCOLOR_SCROLLBAR 5

#define CTLCOLOR_STATIC 6

#define CTLCOLOR_MAX 7

#define COLOR_SCROLLBAR 0

#define COLOR_BACKGROUND 1

#define COLOR_ACTIVECAPTION 2

#define COLOR_INACTIVECAPTION 3

#define COLOR_MENU 4

#define COLOR_WINDOW 5

#define COLOR_WINDOWFRAME 6

#define COLOR_MENUTEXT 7

#define COLOR_WINDOWTEXT 8

#define COLOR_CAPTIONTEXT 9

#define COLOR_ACTIVEBORDER 10

#define COLOR_INACTIVEBORDER 11

#define COLOR_APPWORKSPACE 12

#define COLOR_HIGHLIGHT 13

#define COLOR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT 14

#define COLOR_BTNFACE 15

#define COLOR_BTNSHADOW 16

#define COLOR_GRAYTEXT 17

#define COLOR_BTNTEXT 18

#define COLOR_INACTIVECAPTIONTEXT 19

#define COLOR_BTNHIGHLIGHT 20

#if(WINVER >= 0x0400)

#define COLOR_3DDKSHADOW 21

#define COLOR_3DLIGHT 22

#define COLOR_INFOTEXT 23

#define COLOR_INFOBK 24

#endif /* WINVER >= 0x0400 */

#if(WINVER >= 0x0500)

#define COLOR_HOTLIGHT 26

#define COLOR_GRADIENTACTIVECAPTION 27

#define COLOR_GRADIENTINACTIVECAPTION 28

#if(WINVER >= 0x0501)

#define COLOR_MENUHILIGHT 29

#define COLOR_MENUBAR 30

#endif /* WINVER >= 0x0501 */

#endif /* WINVER >= 0x0500 */

#if(WINVER >= 0x0400)

#define COLOR_DESKTOP COLOR_BACKGROUND

#define COLOR_3DFACE COLOR_BTNFACE

#define COLOR_3DSHADOW COLOR_BTNSHADOW

#define COLOR_3DHIGHLIGHT COLOR_BTNHIGHLIGHT

#define COLOR_3DHILIGHT COLOR_BTNHIGHLIGHT

#define COLOR_BTNHILIGHT COLOR_BTNHIGHLIGHT

#endif /* WINVER >= 0x0400 */
```

So, as @CodyGray defined, 1 is added to differentiate between COLOR_SCROLLBAR and a NULL HBRUSH.
And, (Quoting @CodyGray's comment and corecting my solution) "HBRUSH is a C-style cast and you should be using `static_cast<HBRUSH>` instead of a C-style cast."

Comment: HBRUSH is *not* an operator. It's a C-style cast. The documentation you linked to is for the MFC CBrush class, which does provide an implicit conversion operator to HBRUSH. But that has nothing to do with the question here (he's not using MFC) or the sample code provided. And the truth is, in C++, he *should* be using `static_cast<HBRUSH>` instead of a C-style cast.

Comment: @CodyGray : Thanks for the enlightenment :-) I will edit my answer accordingly. Just curious, why don't you provide the solution as it is obvious that you have the in-depth knowledge in this area. Everybody knows on SO that you are an expert. BTW, I like the way you push us beginners on the correct path by hinting us a lot :-)

Comment: `static_cast<HBRUSH>` doesn't work as HBRUSH is defined as `typedef HBRUSH__ *HBRUSH` and so requires a `reinterpret_cast`

Answer (score 9):

Don't you mean?

```
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
```

[GetStockObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144925%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gets one of the stock brushes, pens, fonts or palettes. You should not be using COLOR_WINDOW with it.

Use one of the stock brushes with it, so for a white background you could use...

```
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
```

Whatever works, use it!

Comment: Check the comments to see the reason for +1.

Comment: @HansPassant Interesting, according to MSDN: "the value 1 must be added to the chosen color". That is one major API quirk!

Comment: The deal is, `COLOR_SCROLLBAR`, the first possible value, has the value of 0. So, incidentally, does a null handle to a brush (`NULL`). So, the 1 has to be added to each of the enumerated color values in order to support null brush handles. It makes perfect sense if you understand why, but it is a bit strange at first blush.

Comment: Either of your two options will work and are the correct approaches in this case, but I disagree with the general sentiment of "whatever works, use it!" :-)

Comment: Hehe, I guess I have to eat my words there. Remember though you are actually getting WHITE_PEN not COLOR_WINDOW with GetStockObject(COLOR_WINDOW+1).

Answer (score 0):

COLOR_WINDOW is a number. When you add 1 to it you increase the number. (HBRUSH) is there to convert the number to a color code.